# iOS card / grid layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview, tableview, collectionview

I have to design a UI similar to the following. The question is I'm somewhat lost in what controls I should be using to achieve this. Any assistance on right direction is highly appreciated.

Here are few ways I thought of doing but not completely sure if I will encounter problems on the way.

1 - horizontal scroll view with paging and each page has child scrollview which has vertical scrolling

2 - combination of tableview and scrollview ( tablecell has scrollview that allows vertical scrolling)

3 - collectionview with grid / flow like layout, (how do I block certain sections from being browsed)

[image: layout design]

Comment: Unless all of the content is really similar, I'd go with solution #1. Another option would be to use SpriteKit and make each square a separate scene.

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes the content are quite similar on each box. Sprite kit is somewhat out of the question as it is a UIKit application.

Answer (score 0):

I did something that sounds like what you want about five years ago:

http://www.pushplay.net/2010/09/swiping-and-sliding-multi-view-framework/

If I were to redo it, I'd support Storyboards and make everything view controllers instead of views (so it was less "code-based", easier for designers to work with), but other than that, it sounds similar to what you want.